# Open App is shown instead of Update App in App Store when I opened App Store via my App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store

I have implemented functionality in my App to open it in App Store via iTune Link of my App. The issue that I am facing is that whenever my App is updated on App Store and I go to it by clicking the update button inside my App, the open button appeared in App Store instead of the Update button.
When I go to App Store and find my App then it displays the update button but now when I go via my App.

(On Update button click I am doing this)

```
    NSString *iTunesLink = @"itms://itunes.apple.com/qa/app/my-App/id1123444387?mt=8";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Also 
I wanted to convert this swift code to objective c.

```
let urlStr = "itms://itunes.apple.com/qa/app/my-App/id1135248687?mt=8"
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlStr)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

} else {
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appstore App, has tabs one tab is dedicated for showing update available for apps installed on iPhone/iPad.

it is not possible to navigate user to update tab, in past I have tried similar but seems not possible.

swift converted -

```
let urlStr = "itms://itunes.apple.com/qa/app/my-App/id1135248687?mt=8"
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
}
do {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:urlStr)
    , options
    , completionHandler
    nil

}
do {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:urlStr)
}
```

[converted using online tool](https://objectivec2swift.com/)

**Disclaimer** I am not associated with above mention product, I have just used it and finds ok, hence recommending

Answer (score 0):

ObjC code:

```
     NSURL * urlStr = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/qa/app/my-App/id1135248687?mt=8"];

     if(@available(iOS 10.0,*)){

         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlStr options:@{} completionHandler:nil];

     }else {

         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlStr];
     }
```

As for the update button problem check your link as it may be pointing to a different location.

In your case it should look something like this:

@"itms://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1135248687?mt=8"